# Facing issues in MySql and SqlYog using together

Tags: mysql, asp.net, xampp, sqlyog

I have MySQlWorkBench and SqlYog together on my machine.
And I have XAMPP control panel to start Apache and MySql.
When i have only SqlYog then XAMPP was starting the MySql successfully. But after installing MySql, XAMPP never started the MySql immediately and it starts once i stopped one service perhaps having name like "MySql57" from services.msc.
Please suggest how i could handled together the MySql and SqlYog.

And with this please suggest that how could i connect the MySql and SqlYog from ASP.Net application.

I will really thankful to you.